# Какой цикл будет быстрее

Tags: java, коллекции, foreach, generics, for

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add(1);
        arrayList.add("два");

        //Этот?
        for(int i = 0; arrayList.size() > i; i++){
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
        }

        //или этот в котором как я понимаю будет приведение типов?
        for (Object temp: arrayList){
           System.out.println(temp);
        }
```

Знаем, что forEach медленнее при работе с коллекциями, чем for (хотя может сейчас  и это уже оптимизируется) Но накладывает ли приведение типов дополнительные расходы или же компилятор увидит, что я элементы всего лишь печатаю и в любом случае они будут приведены к String и оптимизирует это?

**UPD:** 
 
 В этом случае у нас в листе Integer. в ForEach всё тоже Integer.
 А в первом варианте в forEach был Object.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(5);

 for (Integer temp : arr ) {
      System.out.println(temp);
 }
```

Вопрос в том, будет ли ненужное приведение типов к объекту в forEach , а в for мы к Object не приводим. Вот в этом моменте я запутался

Comment: 1 будет быстрее. Причем гораздо быстрее он будет, если вы `arrayList.size()` сохраните в переменную, а не при каждой итерации. И за место `i++` напишите `++i`.

Comment: нет, вывод arrayList.size() в переменную не дает прироста скорости. Только при первом запуске теста, а потом компилятор оптимизирует  и сам делает этот вывод переменной, так что лучше не портить читабельность кода.

Comment: @And, так же ++i  не дает никакого прироста, наверно тоже оптимизируется. Хотя я даже не понимаю в чем разница ++i или i++ для цикла for  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В этом случае у нас в листе Integer. в ForEach всё тоже Integer. А в первом варианте в forEach был Object.

нет там тоже был `Integer`

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
items.add(1);

System.out.println(items.get(0).getClass()); // class java.lang.Integer
```

---

В java нет шаблонов, есть дженерики (generics) и в ее коллекциях (списки, словари, множества и т.п.) не хранятся простые типы (int, float, boolean, и т.п.), а если и добавляются, то они будут обернуты в соответствующий им класс. Поэтому, в коде `int` стал в списке `Integer`.

Все коллекции хранят значения в типе `Object`

```
ArrayList items_1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Integer> items_2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    items_1.add(i);
    items_2.add(i);
}

long startTime;
int number = 1000000;

startTime = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    for (Object temp : items_1) {
        Integer num = (Integer) temp;
    }
}
System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed time %s nanoseconds", (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / number));

startTime = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    for (Integer num : items_2) {
        // ...
    }
}
System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed time %s nanoseconds", (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / number));
```

Консоль:

```
Elapsed time 892 nanoseconds
Elapsed time 860 nanoseconds
```

Comment: Да да , я знаю что быстрее) Вопрос в другом, он касается именно приведения типов. Сейчас добавлю в вопросе конкретику

Comment: я попробовал поэксперементировать, но использовал очень мало значений и вроде бы приведение типов не влияет ..либо это компилятор дофига умный и видя, что элементы будут только печататься, не делает лишней работы, либо вообще я что то недопонимаю .

Comment: нет, ну это понятно что в коллекциях нет примитивов. Просто мне казалось, что в  forEach всё имеет тип Object , а в for я получаю сразу либо Integer либо String. Но странно, я написал  for (Object temp : items) {
                // ...
                System.out.println(temp.getClass());
            }    И я ожидал получить ответ Object , но я получил Integer  и String

Comment: @Turalllb, я написал почему так. Когда вы пишите `Object obj = new Integer();` вы не трансформируете Integer в Object, а просто меняете информацию о его типе на более базовый, сам объект как был так и останется Integer. И похоже, foreach оптимизирован для вытаскивания указанного типа, т.к. код с ручным приведением типа немного медленнее. Возможно, из-за проверок  типа (если приводить к неправильному типу будет ошибка)

Comment: но ведь Integer сужается до Объекта и теперь имеет только базовые методы. А если сделать обратно, то появятся методы присущие  Integer integer = (Object) obj.   Это ведь и есть приведение типов и на приведение тратится время. Хотя .. getClass ведь не тип возвращается..точно..дошло.

Comment: Да, вот  и я думаю, что к Object он приводится только для нас , для наглядности, а компилятор же делает оптимизацию и если бы я не просто печатал, а с каждым типом как то работал, то оптимизацию сделать не получилось бы . Ладно, спасибо, пора спать, это всё мелочи, но забавные для любителя рефакторинга))

Comment: `но ведь Integer сужается до Объекта `, не, просто доступ ограничивается указанным типом. У Integer есть метод intValue. Если вы Integer приведете к Object, то вызвать intValue не выйдет -- компилятор не даст (т.к. у Object нет такого метода). Но, я думаю, это возможно через рефлексию: `Integer num = new Integer(123);System.out.println(num.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("intValue"));Object obj = new Integer(123);System.out.println(obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("intValue"));`